# Is the lockpicking skill good for anything other than picking locks?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Since skill points are gained rather slowly in Kingdoms of Amalur, I find myself giving quite a bit of thought as to what skill I invest in each level.

I currently have two points invested in lockpicking, and I am wondering if I have any reason to invest any further in the skill.

I find it relatively easy to overcome locks designated as "hard", and I don't mind the mini-game, so the skill's milestones (which allow to force locks with 100% success) aren't overly appealing.

Is there any other use for this skill that I should consider before ignoring it completely? I remember reading somewhere that dispelling, which is similar (albeit more useful to me, as I find dispelling quite harder than lockpicking), is used in place of persuasion during a specific dialog. Something similar could affect my investment in lockpicking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to prove a negative since I didn't do every side quest, but no, I found no other use for Lockpicking throughout the game. Of course, I also didn't find the special case for Dispelling that you mention, either.

If you're good at the lockpicking mini-game, you can definitely save your points for other skills, just as you could with Dispelling if you're good at the dispel mini-game. It seemed to be a commonly expressed sentiment that picking locks was pretty easy and the skill points were a waste. This isn't dissimilar from *Skyrim*, where people similarly ignore the lock picking perks if they happen to be good at the mini-game.

Comment: +1 Completely agree, I can't recall any games where lockpicking could be done manually where you would "need" to waste skill points on improving your efficiency.

Comment: +1 I found this game to have one of the easier lock picking mini games. No extra skill points were required for even very hard locks.

Comment: It's practically waste of points, even if you suck at those mini-games. The only skill that's absolute must have is detect hidden.

Comment: @Ravekner in fallout (3 and NV), if you didn't have the required skill level in lockpicking, you were simply refused to pick the lock.

Comment: @Payo then those were not games where you could lock pick manually, you were required to have the skill.